# How to calculate the average x-coordinate of a region?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, improper-integrals, average

I have a region in the x-y plane. Now I randomly select a point inside or on the boundary of the region. What is the expected value of the x-coordinate of my point? I.e. If I perform this operation infinitely many times, what is the average of the x-coordinate?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

$E[x] = \frac{\int\limits_{\cal R} x\ dA}{\int\limits_{\cal R} dA}$ where ${\cal R}$ is the two-dimensional region (assumed uniform density) and $dA$ is a differential area, such as $dx\ dy$ or $2 \pi r\ dr\ d\theta$.

Comment: Do you have to divide by the area? Edit: by which I mean divide the entire integral by the area of the region R

Comment: Your formula cannot be correct, logically. Imagine a family of rectangles with fixed width and variable height so that the average x-coordinate is always the midpoint of the base. As the height varies, the average x-coordinate does not change, but the value given by your formula changes. Therefore, it is incorrect.

Comment: One does need to divide by the total area. Then you get the center of mass formula often taught in calculus classes.